# Phonegap clearing input on focus

Tags: cordova, input, focus

I have a phonegap application with a bunch of input boxes, somehow when a touch the "next" button in a field, the next field is cleared on focus (Supose it was previously filled with some text).

Does the focus event trigger any other event that I'm not aware of? Is this a common behavior? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below solves your issue.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
});
```